# Getting Pages to Show Up in All Pages

Tags: wordpress

If I create a page with `wp_insert_page()` I notice that it does't show up in the dashboard's All Pages display.  I know the page is being created because I can access it with the link  `[site]/?id=664`,  where `664` is the page id returned by the `wp_insert_page()` call.

Does anyone know why the page isn't in All Pages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_insert_post()`rather than `wp_insert_page()`. Here is an example:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'   => 'page'
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/